# Mostrar un json de forma ordenada

Tags: php, json

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$data = $this->database->obtener_mensaje($_POST['msgid']);  
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Accept");
echo json_encode($data);
```

pero al mostrarlo me imprime el json en una sola linea:

```
{ "status": true, "description": { "message": { "control": "xxxx", "phone": "xxxx", "msg": "Test de Prueba API Respuestas V2", "status": "ERROR GENERIC FAILURE", "loops": "2", "disposicion": "MOVIL", "carrier": "xxxx","received_date": "2021-12-21 18:16:50", "send_date": "2021-12-21 18:18:22", "campo_a": "", "campo_b": null }, "answers": [] }, "code": 202 }
```

¿Existe alguna manera de mostrar el json de forma ordenada?

```
{
    "status": true,
    "description": {
        "message": {
            "control": "xxxx",
            "phone": "xxxx",
            "msg": "Test de Prueba API Respuestas V2",
            "status": "ERROR GENERIC FAILURE",
            "loops": "2",
            "disposicion": "MOVIL",
            "carrier": "xxx",
            "received_date": "2021-12-21 18:16:50",
            "send_date": "2021-12-21 18:18:22",
            "campo_a": "",
            "campo_b": null
        },
        "answers": []
    },
    "code": 202
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con JSON_PRETTY_PRINT puedes hacerlo.

```
$json_string = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $json_string;
```

Comment: Entendido, lo provaré

Answer (score 1):

Hola que tal podrías hacer lo siguiente

```
$data = $this->database->obtener_mensaje($_POST['msgid']);  
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Accept");
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: muchas gracias, lo voy a probar